# IF NOT EXIST batch command for multiple paths?

Tags: android, batch-file

Just making a batch file for an android fastboot assistant. The assistant needs a folder for it to work properly, to check this exists, I used 'IF NOT EXIST' command. Is there a way to check if the folder may exist in different paths? For example, if one user saved the folder to desktop and the other saved it in downloads, is there a way to check the whole system to look for this folder? If not is there any other try command? Thanks.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
IF NOT EXIST %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Oneplusone-ADB-assist\Program-files (
start %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Oneplusone-ADB-assist\Corrupt\Corrupt.bat
start %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Oneplusone-ADB-assist\Corrupt\Corruptmsg.vbs
)
exit
```

Where it says "Desktop" in the path, I would like it to search for multiple paths rather then just Desktop.

Comment: You could search through every directories in `%userprofile%`

Comment: You will have permissions issues if the files exist under another users profile.

Answer (score 1):

Next code snippet checks entire `C:` disk.
Add another `for /F` command to check other disk(s) ([mutatis mutandis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis)):

```
set "_lastfound="
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S /AD /A "C:\Program-files" 2^>NUL') do (
  echo found %%G
  set "_lastfound=%%G"
)
rem [optional] check next disk(s) here 
if not defined _lastfound (
  rem your code here
)
```

For command explanation, type `set /?`, `for /?`, `dir /?`, `if /?` or visit http://ss64.com/nt/ page. Read [about `2>NUL`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [about caret in `2^>NUL`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing different issues here, let's go step by step

1. to check for a given folder in a set of known locations

   try a simple `for` loop with the folder names

   ```
   for %%a in (%USERPROFILE%\Desktop %appdata% %programdata%) do (
     if exist %%a\one echo %%~fa\one
   )
   ```
2. be careful with names that may contain spaces, put quotes `"` around them and remove them with `%%~a`

   ```
   for %%a in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" "%appdata%" "%programdata%") do (
     if exist %%~a\one echo %%~fa\one
   )
   ```
3. make sure you don't misinterpret the existence of a file with the same name, check instead for the `nul` device under that location.

   ```
   for %%a in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" "%appdata%" "%programdata%") do (
     if exist %%~a\one\nul echo %%~fa\one
   )
   ```
4. if instead of a given set of locations, you want to check for a folder in a tree of many possible locations not known in advance, you can use `for /d` with a wildcard character like `*`

   ```
   for /d %%a in ("%USERPROFILE%\..\*") do (
     if exist %%~a\one\nul echo %%~fa\one
   )
   ```
5. if you want to do the checking not only all the existing directories but also the sub (and subsub and subsubsub...) directories as well, recursively, add the `/r` flag and specify the root location where to begin searching

   ```
   for /r "%USERPROFILE%\.." /d %%a in (*) do (
     if exist %%~a\one\nul echo %%~fa\one
   )
   ```
6. and finally take into account that you may need to run this code with admin privileges to overcome access permission in certain folders